# Radio Button List, Check Boxes, Drop Down Lists and Enums/Dictionary Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, enums, drop-down-menu, radio-button

The amount of information out there (and here at SO) is, not to understate it, but . . . overwhelming.

There are tons of examples on how to create Radio Button Lists, Check Boxes and Drop Down Lists in MVC 3 with enums. My problem (and probably the answer is "You can't do that") is that I want uniformity in my code with sparing use of extensions (and most examples have varying types of extensions).

It's enough to make my head explode.

So, although it might be repetitive, and although the post might get closed, I would ask whether or not there was an elegant, simple and possibly common set of MVC3 controls for radio buttons, check boxes and drop downs?

What I'm trying to accomplish:

**Radiobutton**
I'm using these for "Yes/No" as well as longer answers (think: full sentences) that a) won't fit or really look appropriate in a DropDownList and b) just look better as a choice the user can contemplate. I already use the below code with good results, but don't know how to use it for checkboxes or dropdowns if it were possible to do so.

**CheckBoxes**
The obvious choice for "more than one" option, but limited to things that should be displayed.

**DropDowns**
Great for 0-5 answers, as in Choices: "0 (none), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or more", or simple 1-3 word phrases (otherwise, I look to radiobuttons).

My problem:
I am not a programmer. I can certainly disabuse myself of the paradigm (see below) I have come to blindly embrace (because it's been working for my radiobuttonlists), but I want something reusable. To me sometimes "reusable" means similar.

My paradigm (or what I consider similar and would hope I can use in check boxes or drop downs):
I am using enums/dictionarylists for my radiobuttons as follows:

```
public SomethingList Something{ get; set; }
        public enum SomethingList
        {
            Something_Something1,
            Something_Something2
        }
        public class SomethingDictionary
        {
            public static readonly Dictionary<SomethingList , string> nameDictionary = new Dictionary<SomethingList , string>
            {
            { SomethingList.Something_Something1, "Whatever text I want, whether it's Yes/No for a check box, a simple 1-2 word phrase for dropdowns, or long sentences as I use in my radiobutton lists." },
            { SomethingList.Something_Something2, "Whatever OTHER text I want, whether it's Yes/No for a check box, a simple 1-2 word phrase for dropdowns, or long sentences as I use in my radiobutton lists." },
             };
            static string ConvertSomething(SomethingListnamelist)
            {
                string name;
                return (somethingDictionary.TryGetValue(somethinglist, out name))
                    ? name : somethinglist.ToString();
            }
            static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ConvertSomething(SomethingList.Something_Something1));
                Console.WriteLine(ConvertSomething(SomethingList.Something_Something2));
            }
        }
```

Any advice/suggestions? (Or, would I be able to continue my paradigm with checkboxes/dropdowns?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [MVCGrabBag](http://mvcgrabbag.codeplex.com/). It has a common code base for all the inputs. It uses enums and a bit of a different style in terms of getting it to work. But once you get your head wrapped around the basics you will not be disappointed. All you do is do a `@Html.FullFieldEditor` and it takes care of the rest with code. There is basically a Selector.cs and some other files that figure out, much like the `@Html.EditorFor` helper does, what input to create. And instead of using a bunch of `/EditorTemplates/` it just has one that takes care of everything.

It appears to be fairly new, so I trust it will gain momentum. I have to imagine for those of us non-superhuman coders out there that this would alleviate the problem of not having any uniform structure to something that has been around since the dawn of the web (I'm talking inputs).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! That looks real promising for what I needed.